# Is my answer for mean and variance to this Itô integral correct?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

State if the Itô integral exists for $\int_0^T\mathrm{e}^{B_t^2}\,\mathrm{d}B_t$ and calculate its mean and variance.

**Mean**

Since $\mathrm{e}^x$ is continuous and bounded on $[0,T]$, then it is square integrable, i.e.
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^T\mathrm{e}^{B_t^2}\,\mathrm{d}B_t\right)^2=\int_0^T\mathbb{E}\left(\mathrm{e}^{2B_t^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t<\infty.$$
Hence, $\int_0^T\mathrm{e}^{B_t^2}\,\mathrm{d}B_t$ has zero mean.

**Variance**

By Itô's lemma, $B_t^2=2\int_0^TB_t\,\mathrm{d}B_t+\int_0^T\,\mathrm{d}t$.

$2\int_0^TB_t\,\mathrm{d}B_t$ is an Itô integral hence it has mean 0, while $\int_0^T\,\mathrm{d}t=T$. Hence, $B_t^2\sim\mathcal{N}(0,T)$.

Using the moment generating variable of a normal random variable,
$\mathbb{E}\left(\mathrm{e}^{2B_t^2}\right)=\mathrm{e}^{2t}$. The variance of $\int_0^T\mathbb{E}\left(\mathrm{e}^{2B_t^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t$ is then
$$\int_0^T\mathrm{e}^{2t}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{2t}-1}2.$$

Thus, it is an Itô Integral.

Am I right?

Comment: $B_t^2$ is NOT normal, it's the square of a normal random variable, it's Chi square. The Wiener integral (Ito integral of a deterministic function) is Gaussian but this does not apply for random integrands!!

Comment: @Chaos so I answer is wrong?